# Wordpress qtranslate, category archive not found

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, categories, permalinks

Link http://mantaspra.com/category/blog worked just fine before installing qTranslate. Now it's not found. If I deactivate plugin, it works again. My permalink structure is /%postname%/. I tried setting default permalinks, changing qtranslate permalink settings, nothing. Category base is unchanged, empty. Pages and single posts work, but not category view.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following line to your functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'qtrans_convertURL' );
```